# Find and delete specific word of string

Tags: javascript

I have month values in form of string "2015W09" and I also need to remove "0" from it, so the expected text string will be "2015W9". I tried with some techniques but both the "0" has removed.

```
var ref = "2015W09";
```

Comment: Post your techniques

Comment: Why wouldn't it result in `215W9` if you remove `0`? Please be more specific about your input format, or provide more examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily done with a regular expression:

```
ref.replace(/W0+/,'W');
```